# Trying to setup 5Gbps setup with APC and AP

Tags: wireless, design

I currently have a 5Gbps line being provided and want to set up an Access Point Controller (WEC-8050) with Access Points (WEA512i) and Cisco Catalyst 2960-x 48 port, is this possible? The APC and Switch only support SFP Port and not SFP+. If this is not viable then any recommendation on APC and AP and Switch that is compatible with 5Gbps?

Comment: It appears the WEC-8050 only has 4 Gig ports, so max of 4Gbps. If you are looking for a solution that can make use of your full 5Gbps, this isn't it. Btw, product recommendations are generally not on topic for this community.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

The only device in your list that actually supports more than 1G line rates is the 2960-X with its two uplink ports. Everything else will be limited to 1 Gbit/s.

Aggregating links (where possible) will only enable better sharing at 1G for each end node up to the total of the aggregated 1G links (and only in theory, load balancing on LAG is very rarely optimal).

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I'm not too sure if you are referring to the correct switch (my bad for not putting the correct name) our switch has 4 sfp uplink ports. here is the actual model name Cisco Catalyst WS-C2960X-48FPS-L.Also another question, if i plug in a Cat6 ethernet cable from the router with cisco rj45 sfp+ transceiver to the switch will i receive 5Gbps?

Comment: So you don't seem to have *any* 10G (or 5G) port. Where are you trying to get that throughput on? If you connect a 10GBASE-T(?) port to one of the 2960 ports it'll link at 1G or not at all. SFP+ transceivers don't work in an SFP slot.

Comment: so the current setup is as follows
Cisco Router(ASR-920-4SZ-A-1G 4SZ AC) -> Cisco Switch Catalyst WS-C2960X-48FPS-L.
So my question was if I have a RJ45 sfp transceiver plugged in the Router and connect the router and the switch via Cat6 Ethernet cable, would I be able to get 5Gbps from the switch

Comment: No. A 1G switch can't do 5G. You could aggregate five 1G port with the mentioned caveats.

Answer (score 0):

It appears none of the equipment you have available can do anything more than 1 Gbit of throughput on a single connection/interface. Since your internet service is either a 10 Gbit link rate limited to 5 Gbit of service throughput, or a 5 Gigabit MultiGig (NBaseT 802.3bz) connection, you will need equipment that matches the service from your ISP handoff. Your router, ASR-920-4SZ-A-1G, likely also does not immediately support greater than 1 Gigabit throughput/connections unless you have increased its licensed throughput since purchase or modified its equipment options.

You'll need new switches, preferably capable of multiple 10 Gigabit SFP+ ports and matching transceivers and cabling to connect everything together, as well as upgraded licensing and possibly line cards/interface modules on your router. Possibly more upgrades, you should check with your Cisco sales account manager or support for clarification on the recommended license and hardware for 10 Gigabit throughput on that ASR 920 model router.

For wireless access points, there are none that support 5 Gigabit for a single link/client. The upcoming WiFi7 standard should support link rates of about 5 Gigabit but actual throughput of more like 2.5 to 3 Gigabit of real performance in actual use. The kind of internet service you have is meant to provide high throughput for many client devices or servers at the same time, not for a single user device, especially on WiFi.